# Converting Swift arrays into Objective-C arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert an array from Swift array into NSMutableArray to use in Objective-C-code. So far the results have been terrible. This is what I have:

```
var polygon: [CGPoint] = []
//add bunch of CGPoints to polygon
var polygonNSMutable: NSMutableArray = []
//if better way to convert Swift array into NSMutableArray -> please inform me!
for l in 0 ..< (polygon.count-1) {
     //first attempt:
     polygonNSMutable.addObject(polygon[k] as CGPoint as AnyObject) // Cannot downcast from 'CGPoint' to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'     
     //second attempt:
     polygonNSMutable.addObject(polygon[k]) //results: Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
}
```

My question is, how Swift arrays are converted into Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here isn't so much converting Swift arrays as it is storing C-Structs in an `NS<Mutable>Array`

First things first, there's an error in your for-loop.  This:

```
for l in 0 ..< (polygon.count-1) {
```

Should be this:

```
for l in 0 ..<polygon.count {
```

Or:

```
for l in 0 ... (polygon.count-1) {
```

Ok, now to store the C-Struct in an `NSArray/NSMutableArray`, we need to store the points as `NSValue`s.
You could rewrite your current for-loop to be this:

```
for l in 0 ..< (polygon.count-1) {
     polygonNSMutable.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint:polygon[k])
}
```

However, you could just iterate through your points like this:

```
for point in polygon {
    polygonNSMutable.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint:point))
}
```

Although, it might be nice to use the map function if your objc array doesn't need to be mutable:

```
let objCArray: NSArray = polygon.map { (point) -> NSValue in
    return NSValue(CGPoint:point)
}
```